# Is the result of Split matrix on matrix a scalar value?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, row

A,B,indA,indB are nxm matrices, I wrote this code:

```
H=A/indA+B/indB;
```

And I expected that H would be a nxm matrix but H has been computed a scalar value.
I used two for loops:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m

h0(i,j)=A0/indA0+B0/indB0;
    end
end
```

but the H elements are equal value.
I wanted to know how can I compute this formula on every elements of the matrices A,indA,B,indB and get a matrix as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H = A ./ indA + B ./ indB;` - You want [element-wise division](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html#bvg3oy_-2?s_tid=doc_ta)